# Take all items in sub-categories using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to take all items in current category and all sub categories that are linked to current one. Currently I do so using recursive function, but I suspect that it can be done just by modifying query. Main reason is that I want to use `.Skip()` and `.Take()` but it won't make any difference if I still have to take all categories first using recursion.

### Database

[image]

### My recusive function that does what I want

```
public static IQueryable<Models.Item> Items(int id, List<Models.Item> items)
{
    if (items == null)
    {
        items = new List<Item>();
    }

    ModelDataContext _db = new ModelDataContext();

    var currentCategory = _db.Categories.Where(x => x.ID == id).Single();

    items.AddRange(currentCategory.Items);

    foreach (var c in currentCategory.Categories)
    {
        Items(c.ID, items);
    }

    return items.AsQueryable();
}
```

tl;dr;

Have recursive function that gets all items in category and sub-categories. Wonder if it's possible just by LINQ itself.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible using just LINQ. However, it is possible to do it with one query if you use a recursive CTE.

Comment: @Qmal I think Ian is right.  This question is pretty similar to the one you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435229/hierarchy-problem-replace-recursion-with-linq-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither EF or LINQ to SQL support eager loading of self-referencing objects. It could be possible if they supported the new HeirarchyID, but alas, neither platform has real support for that at this point either.