# How to know if the user has permission on a parent node of a tree?

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, recursion

I have a tree like representation of a company, it is stored in the database as the following table:

```
  ID       ParentID     Name
 ==================================
   1        NULL        Company
   2        1           Division one
   3        1           Division two
   4        1           Division three
   5        2           Department 1.1
   6        3           Department 2.1
   7        3           Department 2.2
   8        3           Department 2.3
   9        4           Department 3.1
  10        NULL        Company 2
```

Now, when I give permission to a user, I need to assign him for a group from the above table, if I assign him for a group he will automatically have permission on the child groups. I can easily check this if it's about one group. But for example if I give the user permission on (division 2) and then the user is making some transaction on (department 2.2) I need to find a way that automatically permits the transction because the user is already permitted on a parent group. I can only think of recursive method where I check the targeted group and if user has no permission on it and it has a parent group then I recall the same method to authenticate its parent and so on until I find a group which the user is permitted for or reach the root group and not authenticate the user. Remember the child can have another child within it and so on.

Is there a way to do this in a better way? Either with Linq or plain old T-SQL?

Comment: I assume you're asking if I have someone who has access level 3, how do I check to see if they have access to level 8?

Comment: No, for example, group (H) is a grand grand child of group (B). Now who ever has permission on Group B will have permission on all its childs. So I need a way to check that.

Comment: I don't see a group B or group H in your example.  I only see IDs and Names.  In my original question I probably should have been more specific by saying a person with Access ID level 3 is trying to modify an item with Access ID level 8.  Most likely this can be done without Recusion with a simple while statement.

Comment: Sorry, I made up this example from my head. An example from the table above is already mentioned in the question. I think I am finding hard time to choose the right words..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
public class Permission
{
  public ID { get; set; }
  public ParentID { get; set; }
  public Name { get; set; }
}

int userPermissionID = 3;  // Division two
int objectPermissionID = 7; // Department 2.2
bool hasAccess = false;

List<int> check = new List<int>();
check.add(objectPermissionID);

hasAccess = userPermissionID == objectPermissionID;

while(!hasAccess && check.count > 0)
{
  var permissions = context.Permissions
    .Where(p => check.Contains(p.ID))
    .ToList();

  hasAccess = permissions.Any(p => p.ParentID = userPermissionID)

  check = permissions.Select(p => p.ParentID).ToList();
}

if (hasAccess)
{
  ..
```

You would access the database up to X times, where X is the number of sub-branches available.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK recursive function is only way to go. Some time ago I asked similar question and realized EF nor LINQ cannot compute that for you.

My question: [Take all items in sub-categories using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498976/take-all-items-in-sub-categories-using-linq)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to check all child of a parent.

```
with tmp as (
  select id, parentId, name, 0 as iteration
  from t
  where id = 3 -- you wanted parent
  union all
  select parent.id, parent.parentId, parent.name, child.iteration + 1
  from tmp child
  join t parent on child.id = parent.parentId
)
select id, parentId, name from tmp
order by iteration
```

Demo: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5d1d/10