# How to do a recursive query in Linq2Sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following table, MenuItems, in the database:

```
ID  ParentID  Name
--- --------- -----
1   0         Item 1
2   1         Item 2
3   1         Item 3
4   0         Item 4
5   3         Item 5
```

I want to write an extension method to get all menu items to the root of the tree. Something like this:

```
public IQueryable<MenuItem> GetToRoot(this IQueryable<MenuItem> source, int menuItemID)
{
    return from m in source
           ????
           ????
           select m;
}
```

If I call this extension method with the data above for the menu item with ID 3, I should get:

```
ID  ParentID  Name
--- --------- -----
1   0         Item 1
3   1         Item 3
```

Is this possible with Linq2Sql with only one call to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do it in a single query, and here's my thinking: discovering an item's parent effectively requires one join of the table with itself.  Each additional menu level requires one more join of the table with itself.  How many joins/additional levels will you need to reach the root?  You won't know until you perform each one, right?  So, whether on the database/SQL side or in LINQ to SQL, you'll have to take each step one at a time.

If you know your menu system won't go beyond a certain depth, I suppose you could set up a LINQ to SQL query that joins the table with itself that number of times, but that sounds ugly.

What I would suggest is setting up an association of the table with itself in your DBML designer, that would give you a parent `EntityRef<>` property on the class.  Since cycles are not allowed in your `LoadOptions` (and therefore the parent cannot be pre-loaded), you could force the lazy load of the parent in the entity's partial `OnLoaded()` method.

**Here are some relevant SO questions:**

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435229/hierarchy-problem-replace-recursion-with-linq-join](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql)
[LINQ to SQL for self-referencing tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111/linq-to-sql-for-self-referencing-tables)

**Here is a server-side/SQL treatment of the problem:**

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql

**Here is someone who has written some helper code:**

http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET18