# How to get all descendants of some node whis Linq-To-Entites?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, recursive-query

I need to get recursively all **descendants** of some node. For example for node with Id=1 I need to get following descendants: 2,3,4,5,6. For node with Id=2 I need to get nodes:4,5,7.  How I can to do this win Linq-To-Entites with minimum requests to server?

```
    | Id | ParentId | Name |
    ------------------------
    | 1  |    1     |  a   |
    ------------------------
    | 2  |    1     |  b   |
    ------------------------
    | 3  |    1     |  c   |
    ------------------------
    |  4 |    2     |  d   |
    ------------------------
    |  5 |    2     |  e   |
    ------------------------
    |  6 |    3     |  f   |
    ------------------------
    |  7 |    5     |  g   |
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111/linq-to-sql-for-self-referencing-tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to execute it by single request is to use ExecuteQuery for stored function in SQL  database. While this stored function will use [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28SQL.105%29.aspx) for recursive query.

Please mark this as Answer if it resolve the issue.